# Is it possible to read from the NIDAQ card's clock system using Python?

Tags: python, nidaqmx

I'm new to the nidaqmx library, and I wondered if there is a way to read from the default sample clock in the NIDAQ(USB-6346) card. I want to do this to figure out the time it takes to collect a particular number of samples. Any responses/solutions would be much appreciated! This is also the first question I posted on Stackoverflow, so I'm unfamiliar with the formats and such.

What I tried:

I tried using the time/datetime modules in Python already, but it doesn't seem like a very accurate way to measure the (elapsed) time it takes to collect samples. For example, If I use that to find the time it takes to collect 10 samples at 10Hz, the output would be 1.02 seconds rather than 1 second.

I've also tried accessing the default clock through the methods in the nidaqmx documentation and searching in the Stackoverflow/ni community discussion forums, but I still have difficulties finding a way actually to get outputs from the clock.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Open ended and opinion based questions that boil down to subjective responses are generally not a good fit for this site, since there generally is not a single correct answer but a range of opinions based on different approaches. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and [mre] then edit your post.

Comment: @itprorh66 I read stackoverflow's introduction regarding how to post, and I understand that open-ended questions are not right for stackoverflow, but I don't understand how my post so far requires an opinion based answer? The question is "What must be done to read from the NIDAQ card's default sample clock?"